# search manual containing git

Tags: linux, unix

How do I search the manual page names and descriptions for anything containing git in linux? I literally cannot find the answer anywhere. If anyone also knows good command learning resource for linux would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all man pages with `man -k .`. The last '.' is a regular expression. If you search for "git", simply use `man -k git`, but this also gives you pages like "isdigit" what is not what we want. Maybe we search for a full word in the regular expression which can be done with `man -k "<git>". Now you get a long list of all the git pages.

For your second question, there is no "command learning resource". A linux/unix system is what you summarized in it. As this, as more programs you have installed as more "commands" are available. Maybe you want to start with learning the shell internal commands, so you take a look for `bash` or any other shell you prefer.

As always: A good beginner book is always a good resource!

Comment: thank you so much!